# C++ Returning pointer of pointers | Binary Tree get nodes by level

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree

I have this getTreeLevel function, which works perfectly.

```
    void getTreeLevel(int level, int * size, Node* current, Node** result) {
        if (current == NULL) {
            return;
        }
        if (level > 0) {
            getTreeLevel(level - 1, size, current->left, result);
            getTreeLevel(level - 1, size, current->right, result);
        }
        if (level == 0) {
            cout << "Get Level Tree: Adding node to array " << current->val << endl;
            **(result) = *current; 
            (*size)++;
            (*result)++;
        }
    }
```

Then I create this other function, to simplify the complexity of the main.

```
Node** getLevel(int level, int * size) {
        Node* emptyNode = new Node;
        *size = 0;
        getTreeLevel(level, size, root, &emptyNode);
        cout << "There are " << *size << " nodes in the level" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++) {
            emptyNode--;
            cout << emptyNode << " <-> ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        return &emptyNode;
    }
```

When the function it's called in the main:

```
int* size = new int;
    Node ** emptyNode = tree.getLevel(0,size);
    while (*size > 0) {
        cout << (*emptyNode) << " - ";
        (*emptyNode)++;
        (*size)--;
    }
    cout << endl;
```

The output it's:

```
10 - 5 - 4 - 15 - 14 - 16 -
Get Level Tree: Adding node 4
Get Level Tree: Adding node 14
Get Level Tree: Adding node 16
There are 3 nodes in the level
0000021DE92DC850 <-> 0000021DE92DC830 <-> 0000021DE92DC810 <-> // If I change the cout << (*emptyNode) << " - " for cout << (*emptyNode)->value << " - " then I would get 16 <-> 14 <-> 4 <->
0000021DE92DC810 - 0000000000000023 - 0000000000000023 -
```

In a Nutshell: This is a fragment of a binary tree.
I tried to implement a function which uses getTreeLevel. The idea was to decrease the level of complexity in the main.
It was successfully implemented theorically.

The problem here it's that the array kinds of faints away outside the function.
We create a pointer, and then send that pointer's memory address as parameter in the function.
Once finished, we print the array backwards (or address memory, in this case) to return the pointer to the start of the array and returns it.
Once returned, only the "head" or first memory address remains the same. But adjacent address memory seems to change!

What could you recommend me in order to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This won't work:

```
void getTreeLevel(int level, int * size, Node* current, Node** result)   
{
    [...]
        (*result)++;
}
```

Reasoning:  Since `result` is a `Node **`, then `*result` is a `Node *`, i.e. a pointer to a Node.  So far, so good, but now you are incrementing that pointer, which is an operation that only makes sense if the pointer was pointing to an entry within an array.  But in at least one case, it clearly isn't an entry in an array:

```
    Node* emptyNode = new Node;
    *size = 0;
    getTreeLevel(level, size, root, &emptyNode);
```

... so after `getTreeLevel()` returns, emptyNode is pointing to the memory location after the `new Node`, which is to say, to a memory location where no `Node` object exists.  That would explain why you're getting strange results for that Node; you're invoking undefined behavior by trying to use an invalid pointer.

To fix it, you'd either need to make sure that the `Node **` you pass in to the function is pointing to an entry within an array of `Node *`'s (and not just to an individually-allocated `Node`), or you'd need to redesign your algorithm so that it doesn't do pointer-arithmetic on that argument.

Side node:  the following usage of `new` is unnecessary:

```
int* size = new int;
Node ** emptyNode = tree.getLevel(0,size);
```

You'll get better performance (and avoid a memory leak!) by doing this instead:

```
int size = 0;
Node ** emptyNode = tree.getLevel(0,&size);
```